# Finding the distance between current location and another location (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cllocationcoordinate2d, cllocationdistance

I'm not a programmer but have been playing around with a side project for fun. I'm using Xcode 10, Swift 5. I've pieced together a handful of things through youtube and SO but I've searched and experimented with this for three days and I'm running into dead ends here.

I am trying to determine the distance between a user's current location and a preset point (in this case the airport). I am able to find the distance between two hard-coded locations. I am also able to find and print the user's current location in the console. But when I try to combine those I am struggling, most often getting the error

> 'Value of type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' has no member 'distance''

The code that working is and gives me the distance in meters I would like is:

```
lazy var phx = CLLocation(latitude: 33.409016, longitude: -111.805576)
lazy var distanceFromPhoenixToVegas = las.distance(from: phx)
```

And this will print out the current location coordinates:

```
func printCoordinates(){
     if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
            print (location)
     }
}
```

If any one could offer guidance I would appreciate it.

Side note, there are a lot of similar questions on Stack Overflow. There are questions about getting a user's current location, and questions about getting distances between two points. I believe this is essentially what I am asking, but it was only answered by the original poster, and the answer seems not exactly correct to me. [iOS & Swift: display distance from current location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824858/ios-swift-display-distance-from-current-location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`coordinate` is of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D`  You only need `locationManager.location`

```
if let location = locationManager.location {
   print(phx.distance(from: location))
}
```

Comment: I had a few additional errors when I added this. "Value of optional type 'CLLocation?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'distance' of wrapped base type 'CLLocation'" was the first.
`lazy var distanceToAirport = currentLocation!.distance(from: phx)`
Adding the ! resolved that.
I had an if statement later comparing the distance and that threw a `Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CLLocationDistance?' (aka 'Optional<Double>') and 'Int'` error.
I moved the currentLocation variable outside of the function and it resolved that error. 
Thank you SO MUCH.